# How to parsing JSON string parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I send http post from my react app to API like this :

```
const request = new Request('http://localhost:9000/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: new Headers({"Accept": "application/json", 
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"}),
  body: JSON.stringify({ username: username,
               password: password})
})
return fetch(request)
  .then(response => {
    if (response.status < 200 || response.status >= 300) {
      throw new Error(response.statusText);
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(({ token }) => {
    localStorage.setItem('token', token)
  });
```

And I debug it in console on my rails app, and this is the output :

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"{\"username\":\"qqqqqq\",\"password\":\"ssssss\"}"=>nil, "controller"=>"sessions", "action"=>"create"} permitted: false>
```

How do I parsing the params above, I need get username & password params ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this with native Ruby JSON library:

```
@json = JSON.parse(request.body.read)
username = @json['username']
password = @json['password']
```

You take the POST request data and then parse to JSON.

Comment: Thanks charliesttrada

Answer (score 1):

I might be late to answer, but maybe I can help anyone, who stumbles upon this thread.

In your React application you set the `Content-Type` header to type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, but your body is in JSON format. Hence, your Rails app does not parse the parameters correctly due to the wrong content type.

The solution would be to set `Content-Type` to `application/json;charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score 0):

rails provides a [JSON class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/JSON.html) that codes and decodes json for you.